# Between operator in DocumentDB query

Tags: c#, between, azure-cosmosdb

Can Between operator used in documentdb for date data types?

my query is something like

```
"select * from doc where doc.class= 8 AND doc.section= 'A' and doc.dateOfBirth Between 7/20/1995 12:00:00 AM and 7/27/2015 11:59:59 PM"
```

It is returning an exception with message bad request.

> {"Message:
>   {\"errors\":[{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":167,\"end\":169},\"code\":\"SC1001\",\"message\":\"Syntax
>   error, incorrect syntax near '12'.\"}]}\r\nActivityId:
>   71af58f5-5b60-467a-97f4-eec9b91e0d50, Request URI:
>   /apps/4c8d65d7-216b-46b4-abb7-52c1a0c7123f/services/b86da69b-7112-4c42-89c8-d97ca2f0bed6/partitions/07e9f066-670b-4b4b-96a8-352ed4a8c477/replicas/130810328249395810s"}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BETWEEN can be used against any JSON primitive type (numbers, strings, Booleans and nulls). Between operator can't apply on date data type however If you always convert your dates to UTC and store them as strings in ISO 8601 format, standard string sorting will work.

Answer (score 2):

You have a double `and` operator here

```
doc.section= 'A' AND  and doc.dateOfBirth
```

and you're closing a parenthesis at the end of the query, but you haven't opened one

```
12:00:00 AM and 7/27/2015 11:59:59 PM)
```

The `between` operator is supported as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-keywords#between).

Comment: I updated question and That was not the issue.   BETWEEN can be used against any JSON primitive type (numbers, strings, Booleans and nulls). does Date data type is json primitive or not?

Comment: No, JSON does not have a date data type.

Comment: To quote the documentation: `BETWEEN can be used against any JSON primitive type (numbers, strings, Booleans and nulls)`

Comment: If you always convert your dates to UTC and store them as strings in [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) format, standard string sorting will work.